# Excel Button to add file Link

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, button

We have some issues on the office getting organized, so I came up with a spreadsheet to do a lot of stuff for us, but I'd like to add the functionality of adding "file links", basically I'd like to create a button, than when clicked, prompts you to find the file you need, then proceed to attach the link for the selected file on the cell next to the button itself.

I found a way on how to do it with excel files, meaning attaching another Excel file to an Excel file, but we need to attach PDF files, the reason we need a button is that we have way too many PDF files to manually add hyperlinks 1 by 1.

So far I have found this script that seems to work attaching ONLY OTHER EXCEL FILES.

```
Public Sub insertFile()

'Select the cell in which you want to place the attachment
Range("D3").Select

'Get file path
fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub

'Insert file
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add _
Filename:=fpath, _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
IconFileName:="excel.exe", _
IconIndex:=0, _
IconLabel:=extractFileName(fpath)

End Sub


Public Function extractFileName(filePath)

For i = Len(filePath) To 1 Step -1
    If Mid(filePath, i, 1) = "\" Then
    extractFileName = Mid(filePath, i + 1, Len(filePath) - i + 1)
    Exit Function
    End If
Next

End Function
```

I get

> run-time error '1004' cannot insert object

when I try to change it to PDF files.

Comment: So you have basically three tasks. 1) Collect a list of the PDF files. 2) Iterate through that list, and 3) add a hyperlink for that PDF to your sheet via code. So start with task 1, and do some research on collecting that list. When you have that worked out, then go on to task 2, solve that, and move on to task 3. Once you've done that, you'll have the work done. Good luck.

Comment: OK, you have *found a script* - and now you need to modify it. What have you tried?

Comment: even as it is it doesn't work properly, it attaches the excel file, then when i try to open it it opens an empty excel file, then closes the main file, it acts weird, if i try to add a PDF file or any other file, it doesnt add it, it says "run-time error '1004' cannot insert object"

Comment: OK, that should probably have been added to your question as well, and also include on which line you get the error, in addition to the values of the variables involved.

Answer (score 1):

Well here's what I would use to let the user pick a pdf to hyperlink:

```
Sub CreateHyperlink()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim LinksList As Range

Set wks = ActiveSheet 
Set LinksList = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'first empty cell after list
    ChDrive "C:\"
    ChDir "C:\Users\User\Folder1\"
    Filt = "PDF Files (*.pdf),*.pdf ," & _
           "All Files (*.*),*.*"
    FilterIndex = 1
    Title = "Select a File to Hyperlink"
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        (FileFilter:=Filt, _
         FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, _
         Title:=Title)

    If Filename <> False Then
       wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=LinksList, _
       Address:=Filename, _
        TextToDisplay:=Filename
    Else
        MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbCritical, "Loading Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I would most likely just attach this macro to the button... You can also let the user name the hyper link, or just have them put a note in the cell to the right or left. GL!~ :)